# Android 8.1 Bluetooth HpfClient no sound

Tags: android-bluetooth

I use a Android 8.1 device act as Bluetooth HFP client device. It can accept a call and terminate a call . 
But no sound come out from the  HFP client device.

```
state = 3device = 50:04:B8:A0:F3:BC
 I HeadsetClientStateMachine: audio event  state = AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED_MSBC
 I HeadsetClientStateMachine: audio event  state = AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED
 D HeadsetClientStateMachine: AM -> HF 7 15
 D HeadsetClientStateMachine: hfp_enable=true mAudioWbs is true
 D HeadsetClientStateMachine: Setting sampling rate as 16000
 D HeadsetClientStateMachine: hf_volume 15
 D HeadsetClientStateMachine: hfp_enable=true
```

From these log , It seems the audio params already be set to audioManager.What can I do to make it work correctly.
Additionally,from the picture below,the red circle segment code was not excuted ,if this affected the result.
[image]

Comment: By the first, are you sure that SCO streams correctly set up in hardware by drivers and correctly processed by the middle layer? You can use ALSA commands to capture and check.

Comment: @hank15 Thanks for your comment.It should be the SCO streams not set up correct. dumpsys media.audio_flinger ,all the input device is NONE

Comment: Do not know if support of HFP client have already been implemented for your hardware platform. If yes, you need just to enale it somethere in device vendor audio HAL. Also check how "hfp_enable" and other hfp_... parameters are processed there. If support of hardware platform is not implemented yet, you also will need to update kernel drivers.